# Media Recorder won't start

Tags: java, android, logcat

I have been trying to use the Mediarecorder but it doesn't start at all giving me the error given below and when I put the recorder.start in a try and catch the recorder.stop doesn't work giving me a similar error, although I wrote the permission code in the Manifest.xml for Recording.Audio and Write_External_Storage.

```
public class Recording extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaRecorder recorder;
private MediaPlayer myPlayer;
private String OUTPUTFILE;
private TextView myCount;
private Button Play;
private Button Next;
private TextView myQuestion;
private int value;


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode){
        case 1:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                // do something


            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording);

    OUTPUTFILE =
            new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
                    "audiorecorder.3gp")
                    .getAbsolutePath();
    myCount  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myCount);
    Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Play);
    Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
    myQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myQuestion);


    //recorder.start();





    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please grand permission to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
        }
    }

    else {

        value = MainActivity.GenerateValue();
        myQuestion.setText(MainActivity.mylist.get(value) + " ./?");
        Play.setEnabled(false);
        Next.setEnabled(false);

        fiveSeconds();

        Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(Play.getId() == R.id.Play){
                    playBack();
                    Play.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause));
                }

                else {
                    stopPlayBack();
                    Play.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
                }

            }
        });

        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Make_Notes.class);
                startActivity(theIntent);
            }
        });



    }


}

private void fiveSeconds() {

    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long milliseconds) {

            //  Log.i("Seconds Left", String.valueOf(milliseconds/1000));
            myCount.setText(String.valueOf(milliseconds / 1000));
            if (milliseconds / 1000 < 4) {
                myCount.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            sixtySeconds();





           recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            //recorder.reset();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUTFILE);
           try {

               recorder.prepare();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            recorder.start();


            Toast.makeText(Recording.this, "Start!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }.start();
}

private void sixtySeconds() {
    CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long milliseconds) {

            // Log.i("Seconds Left", String.valueOf(milliseconds/1000));
            myCount.setText(String.valueOf(milliseconds / 1000));
            if (milliseconds / 1000 < 4) {
                myCount.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }

        public void onFinish() {

                recorder.stop();



            Play.setEnabled(true);
            Next.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }.start();


}

private void stopRecording(){
    if(recorder != null){
        recorder.stop();

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no recorder to play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private void playBack(){

    myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        myPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUTFILE);
        myPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myPlayer.start();


}

private void stopPlayBack(){
     myPlayer.stop();

        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no media to stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



}
```

}

The Logcat error is:

```
09-15 15:48:59.183 20615-20615/com.example.abdullah.be_fluent 
E/MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4
09-15 15:48:59.192 20615-20615/com.example.abdullah.be_fluent 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.abdullah.be_fluent, PID: 20615
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:1309)
    at com.example.abdullah.be_fluent.Recording$3.onFinish(Recording.java:145) // the Recording.java: 145 is in blue which is myrecorder.start//
    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup MediaRecorder only in cases when permissions granted, refactor your code like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // do something
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                    fiveSeconds();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording);

        OUTPUTFILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audiorecorder.m4a";
        myCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myCount);
        Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Play);
        Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
        myQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myQuestion);



        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please grand permission to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
            }
        } else {

            myQuestion.setText("MainActivity.mylist.get(value) +  ./?");
            Play.setEnabled(false);
            Next.setEnabled(false);

            Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (Play.getId() == R.id.Play) {
                        playBack();
                    } else {
                        stopPlayBack();
                    }

                }
            });

            Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(theIntent);
                }
            });
            setupMediaRecorder();
            fiveSeconds();

        }


    }

    private void setupMediaRecorder() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUTFILE);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Zubaidy are all permissions granted?

Comment: @Zubaidy try to remove recorder.reset(); line and change output format to recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)

Comment: I did change the format and commented the .restart but still, it doesn't work, btw I have updated my code above with all the changes and the error too.

Comment: @Zubaidy I have updated the answer, try it. It works for me.

Comment: I did try your code but an error still appears (I have updated the Logcat question above ), but if it works fine in your computer that means there is nothing wrong with the code. Am I right ?

Comment: @Zubaidy issue appears when you are trying to record audio twice or when you start recording for the first time?

Comment: The issue appears when I start the recording whether it first time or not, since the Logcat error has line in blue which directs me to recorder.start when it's clicked. ( at com.example.abdullah.be_fluent.Recording$3.onFinish(Recording.java:145))